# Restore Samsung Recovery Solution Backup Files (.wcl, .w01) using other software

Tags: backup, file-corruption

I know this is a common problem but I can't find a Windows solution online.

My wife's computer was not working so we did a backup using Samsung Recovery Solution before doing a full restore as Basic Restore actually made things worse! Now, despite the fact the the files are all there on an external HDD, SRS refuses to see them and won't restore. Since subsequent searches have proven to me that the software is (to be polite) not of the best standard, we would like to use something else, if possible.

I tried the 7zip idea on one of the files (copying to a safe location first!) and none of the 7zip extensions worked. It seems the files are from WinClone but there doesn't seem to be a way of getting a trial version of that.

Samsung tech basically told us, "the files are corrupt, tough" but I don't buy it as I read a [post on a Mac forum](https://sites.google.com/site/lefranckcom/home/fixandrestoreabrokenwincloneimage) where someone solved it.

Could anyone give me a Windows version of that solution?